# can't install ceph on fedora21

Tags: rpm, ceph, fedora-21

I used 3 fedora21 to install `ceph`, I tried with

```
ceph-deploy install serverc serverd servere
```

but got:

```
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to execute command: rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs --force --quiet http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/fc21/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.fc21.noarch.rpm
```

It seems that the http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/fc21/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.fc21.noarch.rpm no longer available.

How can I fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ceph is actually packaged in the Fedora distribution proper. Therefore, I recommend simply running `dnf install ceph`. (However, do note that Fedora 21 recently hit end-of-life. Please upgrade whenever you have a chance; with the new update tools this should be painless.)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, it's a bug of ceph-deploy, the url is wrong and the right url is download.ceph.com rather than ceph.com. 
The best way to fix it is to download a new version ceph-deploy. You can use pip 
 to install ceph-deploy 1.5.39 like this:

`pip install ceph-deploy`